# Ошибка Recursion is too deep

Tags: bash

Помогите понять в чем проблема, вроде скрипт должен вглубь по папкам копать, а в итоге вроде выходит так, что он выше по иерархии улетает. В консоли жалуется на слишком глубокую рекурсию

код

```
#!/bin/ksh

fileList=

catalogHier()
{

    fileList=( "$1" )
    curContent=`ls --format single-column`
    for str in $curContent
    do
        curWay=`pwd`
        fileList[${#fileList[@]}]="$curWay/$str"

        if [ -d ${fileList[i]} ]
            then
                cd ${fileList[i]}
                fileList=( `catalogHier $fileList` )    
        fi

    done
    cd ../
    echo ${fileList[@]} 
}

finalFileList=( `catalogHier $fileList` )

echo There
flistSize=${#finalFileList[@]} 
# for (( i = 0; i < flistSize; i++ )); do
#   #statements

#   echo "Content : ${finalFileList[$i]}"
# done
```

Попытка решения через find

```
while `read -rd $'\0' file`; do    
    echo "Content $file"   
done < `find  ./dir0 `
```

Comment: а может просто использовать find - он также может найти все файлы рекурсивно? И сделает это быстрее.

Comment: @KoVadim, действительно можно. Просто необходимо потом перебирать найденные файлы `for str in``find ./dir0``; do`, но тогда папки/файлы с пробелами  вименах плохо обрабатываются. Или тут есть тоже как-то более просто способ?

Comment: да, известная штука, суть в том, что по умолчанию - пробел - это разделитель сущностей, поэтому, трюк заключается в замене разделителя (к примеру, на нулевой символ). Вот детальнее http://askubuntu.com/questions/343727/filenames-with-spaces-breaking-for-loop-find-command

Comment: @KoVadim, нашел решение по ссылке . благодарю.

Comment: @KoVadim, есть еще пару вопросов в рамках `find`: почему при выполении скрипта while `read -rd $'\0' file` `; do echo "$file" done < "` `find  ./dir0 `" первой строкой выводится путь к файлу скрипта, который выполняется, а последней строкой выводит `cannot open *последний найденный файл*`

Comment: Ваша команда не запускается. Приводите полную команду, которая работает.

Comment: @KoVadim добавил в конце топика

Comment: [Хвостовая рекурсия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F?wprov=sfla1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

раз вы всё-таки решили воспользоваться программой *find*, то озвучу пару моментов:

1. никаких манипуляций с окончаниями строк для корректной обработки имён файлов, содержащих пробелы и прочие спецсимволы, не требуется:

   ```
   $ touch "файл с пробелами в имени"
   $ find -type f | while read f; do echo "обрабатываем: $f"; done
   обрабатываем: ./файл с пробелами в имени
   ```
2. при использовании переменной, которая может содержать строку с пробелами, например, для передачи её содержимого в качестве параметра какой-нибудь функции/программе, эту переменную надо заключать в двойные кавычки:

   ```
   $ find -type f | while read f; do echo "обрабатываем: $f"; ls -l "$f"; done
   обрабатываем: ./файл с пробелами в имени
   -rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Apr  4 14:08 './файл с пробелами в имени'
   ```

---

по поводу же исходного вашего скрипта — ошибка (как минимум) здесь:

```
if [ -d ${fileList[i]} ]
```

вероятно, вы хотели использовать «i-тый» элемент массива. но, во-первых, переменную надо было указывать как `$i`, а во-вторых, вы не присваивали переменной `$i` никакого значения.

соответственно, выражением `${fileList[i]}` всегда возвращается первый элемент массива. как и выражениями `${fileList}` и `$fileList`.

Comment: спасибо, однако с `find` тоже как оказалось не все сверх гладко. Да  и это не отменяет желания получить ответ на вопрос, заданный в сабже

Comment: @I.Smirnov, я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Так ведь если бы блок условия не  выполнялся, то и рекурсии бы не случилось.

Comment: @I.Smirnov, программирование без отладки — как стрельба по мишени вслепую. воспользуйтесь, пожалуйста, отладочными сообщениями, чтобы понять, что именно у вас в коде происходит: `echo интересующая_переменная`.

Comment: @I.Smirnov, прошу прощения, я ввёл вас в заблуждение. умолчальное поведение у оператора `${var[произвольный-текст]}` — возвращать первый элемент массива. я внёс изменения в ответ.