# Cannot open [No such file or directory]

Tags: bash

Имеется довольно простой скрипт на `bash`. Скрипт выводит пути всех файлов и папок указанной директории. 
Вроде выводит все более-менее правильно, но вот последний найденный файл всегда выводится с

> Cannot open [No such file or directory]

```
currentPos=`pwd`

while `read -rd $'\0' file`; do
    echo "$file"

done < `find  ${currentPos}/dir0`
```

Почему и как этого избежать?

Comment: опишите, пожалуйста, словами, что именно должен делать ваш скрипт.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin дополнил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в ответе к предыдущему вашему вопросу я [подсказал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/509673/178576) уже, как использовать команду *read*.

напишу ещё раз, максимально придерживаясь вашего примера:

```
currentPos=`pwd`

find  ${currentPos}/dir0 | \
while read file; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: да, спасибо, невнимательно прочитал)